# BroadcastReceiver reconectarse durante delay

Tags: java, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Hola Tengo un BroadcastReceiver y responde bien. Estoy usando un layout personalizado por si no hay conexión que al cabo de 10 seg no aparezca el dinosaurio de google. 
 Ahora resulta que además de que llegue a completar los 10 segundos. si vuelve la conexión dentro de esos 10 segundos debería quedarse en la pagina sin salirse. Y no lo consigo. Vengo 1 semana casi sin dormir para llegar al broadcastreceiver. Cosa que antes no sabia que debía usar y estaba intentando con TimerTask e Hilos . Ahora me trabé aquí. Si pongo todo dentro de una tarea se ejecuta muchas veces y no es la idea.
En si mi problema es que no logro que durante esos 10 segundos si vuelve internet en vez de llevarme al layout personalizado, me mantenga en la pagina web. Ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar.
Saludos ;)

public void checkInternetAcivity() {

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        final int [] type = {ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE};
        conexion = NetworkChangeReceiver.checkInternet(context,type);

        if (conexion) {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
            web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myVisor);
            webView();

        }else {

          /*  if (conexion){
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
                web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myVisor);
                webView();
                handler.removeCallbacks(null);
            }*/

            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sin_conexion);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 10000);
        }
    }
};
```

También probe con un ciclo, pero me sigue pasando lo mismo.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                tareaLarga(); //sleep de 1 seg
                Toast.makeText(context, "conteo: "+ i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(!conexion && i == 10) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sin_conexion);
                }else if(conexion) {
                    webView();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Desconozco el funcionamiento de Android y los entresijos que tiene, pero me imagino que lo que quieres es comprobar cada cierto tiempo si has recuperado conexión. Buscaría lanzar un Task cada 10 seg, desde que detecto que no hay conexión. Si consigue indicarme que ya hay conexión lo envio al Layout. Sino lo vuelvo a intentar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes al querer intentarlo, a los 10 seg, por mas que reanudara la conexión siempre me llevaba al layout personalizado y no me dejaba en la pagina web.

Terminé resolviendo el inconveniente así:
Esto me permitió que al reanudarse la conexión al cabo de 10 seg, no se saliera de la página.

```
if (conexion){
                webView();
            }else {

                handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        if (!conexion) {
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sin_conexion);

                        }

                    }
                }, 10000);
            }
```